# Failed to load resource: the network connection was lost

Tags: javascript, css, safari, loading

The website I developed for a friend is not loading the resource files on every browser, or only once in a while.
The content appears, and the console displays the message "Failed to load resource: the network connection was lost" for every resource files (css and js).

I've checked the syntaxes of every files and there is no error. The main difficulty for me is that it works in every browser on my mac book pro, but doesn't in the safari of my friends iMac or iPad...

Here's the website : http://twennys.com/

Comment: If "_the network connection was lost_" , I'm afraid there's not much SO can do ...

Comment: for me, there is no message saying "Failed to load resource: the network connection was lost", this issue is from your side but for me everything loaded properly

Comment: same here, I use ajax to get data. 99% time it's okay, but for 1%, there is always this weird bug, it happens on safari, ios safari, not test other browers.